# Qt QMouseEvent class

Tags: qt

I'm kind of new to the Qt Framework and was trying to program a game and realised there is no signal for "rightclick()". I read through the documentation and found out I had to use the "QMouseEvent" class but I just can't figure out how it works.. Somebody help me.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Qt::MouseButtons QMouseEvent::buttons() const`.
It returns, according to Qt documentation:

> Returns the button state when the event was generated. The button state is a combination of Qt::LeftButton, Qt::RightButton, Qt::MidButton using the OR operator

So All you need to do is:

```
void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *e) {

    if(e->buttons() == Qt::RightButton)
        qDebug() << "The right button was clicked";
}
```